# Creating both style images using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I just started using the paperclip plugin. I managed to make it work with a normal file field. From Ryan Bates's screencast, I saw that you cannot have a thumbnail image, unless you resize it explicititly at upload time. However, I would like to have both a normal image, and a thumbnail image of the same picture. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create several styles like

`:styles => { :normal=> "1024x768>", :thumb => "100x100>" }`

for exapmle

Then you can use in your view

`<%= image_tag imageable.image.url(:normal) %>`

where imaageable is an object which you have attached an image to

Comment: And on the filesystem, this would create 2 separate files, right? Could you please post a small snippet on how to use each?

Comment: Right it will create 2 separate images.

Comment: As I get this question there is no need to mention `:normal => "1024x768>"` just `:styles => { :thumb => "100x100>" }` is enough. Cause it will then creates an another image called normal with original one. So, in the end he'll be having 3 images instead of 2.